# Prove $|\cos z|^2=\cos^2x+\cosh^2y$

Tags: complex-analysis

That what I tried 
$$
\cos z= \cos (x+iy)= \cos x \cos iy- \sin x \sin iy=\cos x \cosh y-i\sin x \sinh y\\
|\cos z|^2= \cos^2(x) \cosh^2(y)+\sin^2(x)\sinh^2(y)\\
\sinh^2(y)=\cosh^2(y)-1
$$
Then
$$
\cos^2(x) \cosh^2(y)+\sin^2(x) \cosh^2 (y)-\sin^2 (x)= \cosh^2 (y)-\sin^2 (x)
$$
 What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Isn't it $|\cos z|^2=\cos^2x+\sinh^2y$?

Comment: I found it like that in a reference  but I guess it's  wrong I better look for new reference 

Answer (score 2):

The formula you want to prove is wrong: for $z=0$, we have $\lvert\cos0\rvert^2=1$, whereas $\cos^20+\cosh^20=2$.

\begin{align}
\lvert\cos z\rvert&=
\cos^2x\cosh^2y+\sin^2x\sinh^2y\\
&=\cos^2x\sinh^2y+\cos^2x+\sin^2x\sinh^2y\\
&=\cos^2x+\color{red}{\sinh^2y}
\end{align}

Your formula is correct as well.

Comment: I guess some problems in references are  wrong  thank you so much sir

Answer (score 2):

The statement you're trying to prove is false.

What is true is:
$$
|\cos(x+iy)|^2=\cos^2x+\sinh^2y
$$
which can be immediately found rewriting your 3rd line as
$$
\cosh ^2y=1+\sinh^2y
$$
and putting this in
your 2nd line.

Comment: @OmarEafoe: you are welcome! :-)